# Window operations with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a new window with width 600 and height 300

Does jquery have a function to do it ?

Comment: i think you have to look at this for ask a better question ---->> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a new window when clicking a hyperlink?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580987/how-to-open-a-new-window-when-clicking-a-hyperlink)

Comment: ...or generally: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+open+new+window+with+size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, jQuery doesn't have any method for that. You just use plain Javascript.

Example:

```
var handle = window.open('NewPage.html', '_blank', 'width=600,height=300');
```