# how to set action url and change css

Tags: url, wordpress

I have a button that when pressed opens a window on the screen
Is there a way I can get the window to open automatically with a URL?
An example of this site http://karevn.com/ have the button FEEDBEACK
I want the window will open only with a command URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you mentioned is using this plugin -> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/usernoise/

However the plugin is not upto date so just test it before using it on yours taking a back up copy of the files/database.

Comment: I want to make a link that i can give my user and
this windows will open Automatic
like: www.mysite.com/?scriptopenwindow

Comment: @NirAsaf what do you maean by this line -> "and this windows will open Automatic like: "

Answer (score 0):

karevn use a jquery plugin like the FancyBox ( see the ajax part or iframe in this page http://fancybox.net )

Comment: but can i make this windows to open just by set a URL

Answer (score 0):

Open a window with a hyperlink

[How to open a new window when clicking a hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580987/how-to-open-a-new-window-when-clicking-a-hyperlink)

If you want the feedback button then

http://www.script-tutorials.com/css3-modal-popups/

Goodluck