# Get bottom-right position based on screen size - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, position, window

In my webpage, I have a hyperlink. On clicking the link it will open another window.

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"javascript:window.open('https://www.domain.com', 'window_name', 'height=220,width=200,top=450,left=500'); \"  >Open Window</a>";
```

What I need is :

1) Is there any way to open a new window (not new tab) without using javascript? I tried with `target="_blank"` and it opens in new tab only.

2) How can I find top and left positions of the window dynamically based on the screen size? The window should be positioned in bottom-right of the screen. I found the JS code for that. But as I'm using PHP, how can I get it? Can I use JS inside PHP for doing this?

Can anyone help me to find this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the solution for the first question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580987/how-to-open-a-new-window-when-clicking-a-hyperlink and for the second i'm note sure you can do it with PHP which is a server-side langage

Comment: PHP is server side scripting, which means it does not render anything on the client.  It can write script (html, css, etc) to stdout which the web browser/client can then read and process. From a web browser, you do not have direct access to a users desktop -- consider a browser like a virtual container for your program.

Comment: As for getting the screen size, an ECMA compliant interface is accessible using Javascript :  [this should get you started](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_height.asp).  Even if you did manage to execute javascript inside php, you would end up with at best, the screen dimensions of the server, as the server would then be the client container for the execution